# How long variables and array will retained in browser memory?

Tags: javascript, browser

Inorder to reduce server load, I would like to bring many task into client side. There is no clear information about browser memory limit and its recycling ... Just like PHP session is there any clean function or any limit of storage size for browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic javascript variables will last only for the duration of the page

For more persistent variables, use either sessionStorage (these will last until the user closes their browser/tab) or localStorage (these will last "forever"/until the user clears their personal data)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Note that the above are available in all modern browsers, but notably not in IE<=7, in which case you would need to use cookies as a storage mechanism. However, if you need that, you can probably find a library that will take care of the nitty gritty details

Comment: Oh, as for storage size, with localStorage you can definitely get away with a few megabytes no problem. If you need more, it would require testing.

For cookies, no more than a kilobyte max. And all of this would be sent with every http request so it's not really great when you want to reduce server load

Comment: cookie storage is extremely limited....since cookies get sent withevery http request. For large storage...can use feature detection for local....and use server as backup for non available browsers..just adding another 2 cents